# How to Purges data in an Log Analytics workspace with "between" operator by API?

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

I want to purges data for my custom log with TimeGenerated range.

Sample Request

```
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000000/resourceGroups/OIAutoRest5123/providers/Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/aztest5048/purge?api-version=2020-08-01
```

Request Body

```
{
  "table": "MY_CUSTOM_TABLE",
  "filters": [
    {
      "column": "TimeGenerated",
      "operator": "between",
      "value": ["2022-01-02T04:00:00","2022-01-07T03:59:59"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Response Code: 400

Response Body:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "The request had some invalid properties",
    "code": "BadArgumentError",
    "correlationId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000000",
    "innererror": {
      "code": "QueryValidationError",
      "message": "The user with object Id '00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000000' does not have the role 'Data Purger' required to perform purge operation on this resource"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you try passing the `value` in the filters body with this 
"value": "(datetime(2022-01-02 04:00:00)..datetime(2022-01-07 03:59:59))"

Comment: I got "message": "values must be array of length 2" after I try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "message": "The user with object Id
> '00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000000' does not have the role 'Data
> Purger' required to perform purge operation on this resource"

Looking at the Error Message that you have shared above, it is moreover related to access issue. You need to have `DataPurger` RBAC role on that resource inorder to perform data purge over a particular table in log analytic workspace.

Here is the reference documentation for more information about [DataPurger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#data-purger) RBAC role.

We have tested this in our local environment , it is working fine.

In our local environment , we have tried to purge the `heartbeat` table using the above shared [Purge REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/loganalytics/workspace-purge/purge) of Azure Log Analytics workspace.

if you are using the `between` operator in the body of your restAPI , the value should be array of items.

**Here is the sample request & body of the Rest API :**

```html
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/{workspaceName}/purge?api-version=2020-08-01
```

**Body:**

```
{
  "table": "Heartbeat",
  "filters": [
    {
      "column": "TimeGenerated",
      "operator": "between",
      "value": ["2022-01-18T05:40:00","2022-01-18T05:50:59"]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Here is the sample Output for reference:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks ! I got an operationId now but the purge status is "pending" after i post the x-ms-status-location url. Is data-purge work for custom log?

Comment: @EEEEH - based on my understanding yes data-purge work for custom logs as well. As per the documentation majority of purge operations may complete much quicker than the SLA, the formal SLA for the completion of purge operations is set at 30 days due to their heavy impact on the data platform used.

Comment: Do you know how much time cost after purge data? Because the status is "pending" for hours and log still in custom table.

Comment: As mentioned in this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/personal-data-mgmt#view-and-export),While the vast majority of purge operations may complete much quicker than the SLA, the formal SLA for the completion of purge operations is set at 30 days due to their heavy impact on the data platform used.